# this.optional() in jQuery validation method doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've got a little problem here.
I've got the following rule for one of my fields:

```
StartDate: {
    required: isDelayed,
    dateRU: true
}
```

isDelayed() returns false, so I guess StartDate field should be optional. However if I check it inside my dateRU method:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "dateRU",
    function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || isValidDate($.trim(value));
    },
    "Date is incorrect"
);
```

this.optional(element) always returns false for StartDate. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

UPD. Does optional() returns true only if element is not required **AND IS EMPTY**? 'Cause that may be my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be your `isDelayed` function is not returning what you expect, making it required.  I tested your code using this and it works:

```
function isDelayed() { return false; }
```

[You can see a full working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/PFAcY/), try and see what's different in your code from the demo, my best guess is that `isDelayed()` method, or a difference between your actual and posted code.